# Fill array of points in windows forms

Tags: c#, .net, fill, points

I am using a multidimensional boolen array as a map/relief/mountain.

So basicly, I have:

```
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][#][ ][#][#][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][#][ ][#][#][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][#][ ][#][#][ ][ ][#][ ][ ][#][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][#][ ][#][#][ ][ ][#][#][ ][#][#][ ][ ]
[ ][#][#][#][#][#][ ][#][#][#][#][#][ ][ ]
[ ][#][#][#][#][#][#][#][#][#][#][#][#][ ]
```

as a boolean array of arrays. If the value is true, there should be a dot showing.

Filling with a 1pixel ellipse is very slow.

I tried to fill an array of points with all the "valid" pixels and then use the built in functions, but I couldn't find a fast and good working one.

Comment: How you are drawing? Show the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you just create a PNG with the image you want to display and then draw the image on your graphic in the spot you want it.  These tend to be extremely fast when compared to 
drawing functions.